# Dns.GetHostEntry behind a proxy

Tags: c#, networking, proxy, dns

does anyone know how to resolve an external domain name with Dns.GetHostEntry() **behind a proxy**?

I already tried to indicate the proxy information in my App.config (< defaultProxy >) but it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about an HTTP proxy and the firewall doesn't allow DNS traffic through then it can't be done using the DNS protocol.

One thing you might be able to do is to use an HTTP request against a service like http://network-tools.com and parse the response.

Comment: Behind a HTTP proxy, yes. Of course, the DNS protocol should be blocked :) Will find another way. Thanks!