# When resolving DNS Servers and there is a proxy does it need to go through the proxy?

Tags: c#

I have the code below to resolve DNS Servers.  When there is a Socks 4, Socks 5, or HTTP proxy, should it be changed to use the proxy?  If so, can you give an example?  Thanks in advance.

```
public static IPAddress ResolveHostName(string host)
{
    if (host.ToLower() == "localhost" || host.ToLower() == Environment.MachineName.ToLower())
        host = "127.0.0.1";

    IPAddress result;

    //This will parse IPV4 and IPV6
    IPAddress.TryParse(host, out result);

    //Not an IP Address but a server name
    IPAddress ipAddress = result ?? Dns.GetHostEntry(host).AddressList[0];

    return ipAddress;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910641/dns-gethostentry-behind-a-proxy